# How to define JSON Schema that requires an array of objects to contain at least 2 properties of a certain value?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema

I have a dataset that looks like this:

#### Valid Example Data

```
{
  type: "step",
  label: "Step 1",
  fields: [
    // An optional field
    {
      type: "email",
      label: "Your Email"
    },
    // A field that is required and can be either amount|preset
    {
      type: "amount",
      label: "Amount"
    },
    // A field that is required and can be either credit_card|ach
    {
      type: "credit_card",
      label: "Credit Card"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `fields` array can contain many objects of various types. The above example would be valid.

#### Invalid Example Data

```
{
  type: "step",
  label: "Step 1",
  fields: [
    {
      type: "email",
      label: "Your Email"
    },
    {
      type: "credit_card",
      label: "Credit Card"
    }
  ]
}
```

This should error as it does not include an object of type `amount` or `presets`

#### Validation Rules

In order to be valid, `fields` needs to contain 2 objects.

- 1 of them must be of either `{ type: "amount" }` or `{ type: "presets" }`
- 1 of them must be of either `{ type: "credit_card" }` or `{ type: "ach" }`
- Any combination of the 2 would make `fields` be valid.

### JSON Schema

Here is my (failing) JSON Schema:

```
{
  "title": "step",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "title": "type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "label": {
      "title": "label",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fields": {
      "title": "fields",
      "description": "Array of fields",
      "type": "array",
      "additionalItems": true,
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "anyOf": [
          { "properties": { "type": { "enum": ["amount", "preset"] } } },
          { "properties": { "type": { "enum": ["credit_card", "ach"] } } }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  "required": ["type", "label", "fields"]
}
```

[Here is the JSON Schema Validation Reference](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html)

I think between `contains`, `anyOf`, `allOf`, `oneOf`, and `enum` I should be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your `/properties/fields` schema.  That expresses the constraints you need.  Remove `/properties/fields/items/anyOf` (it's wrong) and `/properties/fields/additionalItems` (it doesn't do anything).

```
"allOf": [
  {
    "contains": {
      "properties": { "type": { "enum": ["amount", "presets"] } }
    }
  },
  {
    "contains": {
      "properties": { "type": { "enum": ["credit_card", "ach"] } }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. It should be noted too that `contains` was only implemented in v6 and some validator libraries out there may not support it. In this case it necessitated a switch from `jsonschema` to `ajv` npm libs.

Comment: @elzi Yes, I used it because it was mentioned in the question.  It is possible to express a `contains` constraint without draft-06, but that's a different question :-)

Comment: For sure! I mentioned it only for future readers - not any oversight on your part :) Thanks much.